# Properties of Ultrafilters

Tags: filters

Let $X$ be a subset such that $X\neq \varnothing$. I want to prove that if $U$ is a ultrafilter, then for all $A\subset X$, either $A\in U$ or $X\setminus A \in U$. 
I suppose that $A\notin U$. Why $U\cup \{A\}$ cannot be extended to a filter on $X$?
Can you help me try it?

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathcal{U}$ is an ultrafilter, it means it is a maximal filter, and so $\mathcal{U} \cup \{A\}$ cannot be extended to a filter if $A \notin \mathcal{U}$, because such a filter would **contradict** the fact that $\mathcal{U}$ is a maximal filter.

Now this implies that

$$\exists A_1 \in \mathcal{U}: A_1 \cap A= \emptyset\tag{1}$$ because otherwise

$$\forall A_1 \in \mathcal{U}: A_1 \cap A \neq \emptyset\tag{2}$$ and then

$$\ \mathcal{F} = \{C \subseteq X: \exists C' \in \mathcal{U}: C' \cap A \subseteq C\}$$

would be a filter extending $\mathcal{U}$ and containing $A$ (check the definitions!), which cannot happen as we saw.

So $(1)$ holds and then $A_1 \subseteq X\setminus A$ and so $X\setminus A \in \mathcal{U}$. So $A \notin \mathcal{U}$ implies $X\setminus A \in \mathcal{U}$.